# Ubuntu 22.10 Cannot install pgadmin4

Tags: 22.10, pgadmin

I follow this instruction

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
# add the following line:
deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ kinetic-pgdg main
sudo wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update
sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

but I still get:
`` package `pgadmin4` has no installation candidate ``

May be is there other solution?

```
lev@lev-HP-ProBook-445-G7:~$ sudo apt update
[sudo] password for lev: 
Hit:1 https://repo.yandex.ru/yandex-browser/deb stable InRelease
Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt kinetic-pgdg InRelease [18,9 kB] 
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic InRelease                       
Ign:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu kinetic InRelease
Ign:5 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/kinetic pgadmin4 InRelease
Err:6 https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/kinetic pgadmin4 Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 147.75.85.69 443]
Hit:7 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                  
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-updates InRelease               
Err:9 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.52 443]
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-backports InRelease
Hit:11 https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu/22.20/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Hit:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu kinetic-security InRelease
Hit:13 https://repo.radeon.com/rocm/apt/5.2 ubuntu InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/kinetic pgadmin4 Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/ppa/ubuntu kinetic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/dists/kinetic-pgdg/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt kinetic-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Answer (score 0):

Pgadmin4 as apt is not supported for Ubuntu 22.10. For Jammy, use this:

https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-apt/

Comment: 22.10 is Kinetic. Jammy is 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

I did it using
https://www.how2shout.com/linux/install-postgresql-pgadmin-4-on-ubuntu-22-04-lts-jammy-linux/

But I changed the instructions instead of

```sh
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list'
```

I used

```sh
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/jammy pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list'
```

that did it basically kinetic is not supported yet but the one for jammy works

I only installed the desktop version though not the web form as I did not want that